# What's the proper way to check in a Model's save() method if a FileField was committed in Django?

Tags: python, django

In Django, if you are overriding the `save` method of a model with a `FileField`, you can do something like this:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_file = models.FileField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.my_file and not self.my_file._committed:
            # The file changed
```

This lets you detect anytime a new file is uploaded. This can either happen if a new instance of `MyModel` is being created, or one is being modified, and a new file is replacing an old file (or no file).

This is very convenient for cases where you need to read the file, and do something, but only if the file changed.

This works, but the slight problem is that the `my_file._committed` attribute starts with an underscore, indicating that it's not meant to be used outside of the class it's defined in.

Is there a proper way to detect if the file in the `FileField` changed during the current `save()` operation without using the private `_.committed` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the `self.my_file.instance.attname` of the instance.

From `Django` [source code of `FileField.save` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ba9ced3e9a643a05bc521f0a2e6d02e3569de374/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L87-L95):

```
    def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
        self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
        setattr(self.instance, self.field.attname, self.name)  # <- check the attribute
        self._committed = True


        # Save the object because it has changed, unless save is False
        if save:
            self.instance.save()
```